# Some problem with rotation angles in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I just attached one object to another. I don't understand what happened, but the rotation angles of the child object in the inspector or `myChildObject.transform.rotation.eulerAngles` (or `myChildObject.transform.localRotation.eulerAngles`) are different.

Comment: Please include what you are trying to do and a [mre] which produces the observed behavior.

Comment: Ok, I think, https://answers.unity.com/questions/477417/euleranglesx-stops-at-90.html is related with my question.

Answer (score 1):

The Inspector shows the `localRotation` of objects, which will not change unless you change (or reparent) that specific object. Changing a parent's `rotation` or `localRotation` will never change its (existing) child's `localRotation`.

A child object with `0,0,0` Euler angles just means it isn't rotated compared to its parent -- i.e. its world `rotation` should match its parent's world `rotation`.

Rotating the parent should change the child's *global* `rotation`, but if the child does not have a `localRotation` of `0,0,0` they won't match. For example if the parent had a `rotation` of `45,0,0` and the child had a `localRotation` of `0,0,90`, the child would end up with a global `rotation` of `45,0,90`. (Things can get much weirder than that, though.)

To put it another way, the child's global `rotation` is its own `localRotation` combined with the rotation of its parent/s.